# How to convert quarter in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently working on Oracle SQL and have the following string values:

```
'1/2019', '2/2019', '3/2019', '4/2019'.
```

This values should be transformed like the following:

```
'1/2019' should be convert to '01.01.2019'
'2/2019' should be convert to '01.04.2019'
'3/2019' should be convert to '01.07.2019'
'4/2019' should be convert to '01.10.2019'
```

Is there a way in Oracle SQL to implement this transformation or is it necessary to write my own implementation (for example with SQL Case)?

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  test_inputs (str) as (
    select '1/2019' from dual union all
    select '2/2019' from dual union all
    select '3/2019' from dual union all
    select '4/2019' from dual
  )
select str, add_months(to_date(str, 'mm/yyyy'), 2 * substr(str, 1, 1) - 2) as qtr
from   test_inputs
;

STR     QTR        
------  -----------
1/2019  01-JAN-2019
2/2019  01-APR-2019
3/2019  01-JUL-2019
4/2019  01-OCT-2019
```

The `with` clause is for testing only; what you are looking for is the formula in the main `select`.

I left the result in `date` data type (displayed here using my current session's settings). If you need to convert back to string in the specific format you requested, you can wrap within `to_char(..., 'dd.mm.yyyy')`.

Answer (score 0):

I may take a bit of string manipulation, but this should solve your question:

```sql
WITH test_data (date_string) AS
(
    select '1/2019' from dual union all
    select '2/2019' from dual union all
    select '3/2019' from dual union all
    select '4/2019' from dual
)
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/'||SUBSTR(td.date_string, -4), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), (SUBSTR(td.date_string, 1, 1)-1)*3)
FROM test_data td;
```